# CakePHP - HABTM and different databases for models

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, multiple-databases

Lets say I have two different databases with the following tables:

Auth database:

```
users
```

App database:

```
fanpages
fanpages_users
```

Obviously my User model uses the Auth database, but how do I force HABTM relation to use the App database instead of the Auth database?

The error I am getting states:

```
Table fanpages_users for model FanpagesUser was not found in datasource Auth.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create another model called `FanspagesUser` and define `$hasMany` relation on `User` model and on `Fanpage` model.

## FanpagesUser.php

```
    <?php
    class FanpagesUser extends AppModel{
        public  $useDbConfig = 'your database configuration on databases.php';
        public $belongsTo = array('User','Fanpage');

    }
```

## Fanpage.php

```
    <?php
    class Fanpage extends AppModel{
        public  $useDbConfig = 'your database configuration on databases.php';
        public $hasMany= array('FanpagesUser');

    }
```

## User.php

```
    <?php
    class User extends AppModel{
        public  $useDbConfig = 'your database configuration on databases.php';
        public $hasMany= array('FanpagesUser');

    }
```

Comment: And you just leaved... Why don't you tick this as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, im quite new to SO. Done now.